# Why is iodined significantly slower when I run it from a systemd unit?

Tags: systemd, dns, proxy

When I run iodined from systemd I get 30 second+ pings, but when I use it directly from the linux cli I get reasonable pings of ~60ms.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when launching from systemd the "interval" argument gets changed. Add `-i 4` to your launch arguments for iodined to set it back to the default.